# How to remove a specific pattern from a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

file.log:

```
This is a firstfile.c.txt: 234
This is a secondfile.cpp.txt: 456
welcome to scriptfile.h.txt: 999
```

Output:

```
This is a firstfile.c: 234
This is a secondfile.cpp: 456
welcome to scriptfile.h: 999
```

Can anyone help me to remove the `.txt` from the input file and display the output as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat file.log | sed 's/\.txt:/:/'
```

or

```
sed 's/\.txt:/:/' file.log
```

Comment: ([Useless use of `cat`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Comment: Fair enough. But likely the file file.log was created because the user didn't know that the command that created it could just pipe into sed without making the file in the first place.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk: Escape the dot with a backslash.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk Nevertheless, Biffen's gentle request to edit the answer to: "sed 's/\.txt:/:/' file.log" is a good one.